# Ehcache cannot overflow data to disk in XA Mode (NotSerializableException)

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ehcache, xa

I'm experimenting XA transactions with Ehcache. Currently I'm using Spring transaction management and Bitronix as transaction manager.

I create, configure and fill up a cache using the method below:

```
@Transactional
public void createCache() {
    this.cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration("MyCache", 5000).diskPersistent(false).eternal(false)
            .diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(1).maxElementsInMemory(70).transactionalMode(TransactionalMode.XA);
    final Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setDefaultCacheConfiguration(this.cacheConfiguration);
    final DiskStoreConfiguration diskStoreConfiguration = new DiskStoreConfiguration();
    diskStoreConfiguration.setPath("cache");
    config.addDiskStore(diskStoreConfiguration);
    this.cacheManager = new CacheManager(config);
    this.cacheConfiguration.name("primaryCache");
    this.cache = new Cache(this.cacheConfiguration);
    this.cacheManager.addCache(this.cache);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        final Integer value = Integer.valueOf(i);
        this.cache.put(new Element(value, value));
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine and Ehcache works as expected by evicted elements over the count of 70.

Now if I change `diskPersistent` from `false` to `true`, it does not work as soon as Ehcache attempt to copy some element to the disk storage with the following exception:

```
[primaryCache.data] ERROR n.s.e.s.c.f.DiskStorageFactory btm-gtrid=737072696E672D62746D0000012F9296448C00000000 - Disk Write of 0 failed (it will be evicted instead): 
java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sf.ehcache.transaction.ReadCommittedSoftLockImpl
```

This is *expected* as switching Ehcache to transactional mode makes it replace the original values of `Integer`type by a `SoftLock`:

```
[main] DEBUG n.s.e.t.local.LocalTransactionStore ehcache-txid=0, btm-gtrid=737072696E672D62746D0000012F9296448C00000000 - put: cache [primaryCache] key [0] was not in, soft lock inserted
```

To be complete, this also happens when using the Atomikos transaction manager and works flawlessly when not using XA mode.

The question is: *is there a way to mix XA transactions and disk overflow ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should work as you expect them to but you've just found a bug which completely prevents the Open Source disk persistent store from working with any transactional mode.

Please report the problem in the Ehcache JIRA (https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC) and we'll fix it as soon as we can.

Comment: I forgot to mention: the Enterprise disk persistent store used when Big Memory is enabled (ie: when overflowToOffHeap=true) is not impacted by this bug. You may want to consider it in the mean time.

Comment: Sure but it's not free (as beer) anymore. Anyway the fix is in the trunk and it worked on my test. Thanks.